# which one is correct and why

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm confused about which sentence is correct :

> what control people's life

and

> what controls people's life

I think that the first sentence is correct when we talk about the factor**s** and the second is correct when talking about the **one** factor

Comment: These aren't *sentences*. They're *noun phrases*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second phrase is correct.

> what controls people's life

The reason is because *what* is a question/relative pronoun which is always singular. It requires the verb to be in singular as well. So we use 3rd person singular of Present Simple of the verb 'to control', which is 'controls'.

Comment: [what are your strengths?](https://www.google.ro/search?q="what+are+your+strengths"&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=6znUWI-_GcKe6ATe-qDYCA)